# Shared server resources limits per users

Tags: linux, ubuntu, top, iotop

We have an on-prem Xeon server running Ubuntu LTS that is shared across few developers.
Each developer logs in with his on user and run various workloads on it.
The problem we experience is when sometime runs a CPU or storage extensive workload, the other users can't actually work on the machine, the shell becomes non-responsive.

We tried to ask the user to limit their CPU utilization when building and it solved the CPU issues, but apperently, disk IO utilization continues to be a problem.
We're using SSD storage.

The usage of virtual machine on the server is not a possibility, as we don't want to hard limit the resources. we just want to make sure that there won't be starvation of resources to other users.

What options do we have ?